# Nagios Installation

Tags: nagios3

What command should I use to  search and install nagios plugins when setting up nagios? This is not working 
wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/nagiosplug/nagios-plugins-1.4.11.tar.gz

Please help

Answer (score 2):

There is a package in the Ubuntu repositories - to install it execute:

```
sudo apt-get install nagios-plugins
```

The package is a meta-package and installs all plugins that are available in the repositories.

Comment: Wow it works !!!  thanks  whats your Skype name?

Comment: Don't thank me. Accept the answer with a click on the check mark at the left side of the answer. **;)**

Answer (score 0):

Current version is 2.2.1, and can be found from nagios-plugins.org with the following command:

`curl -L -O http://nagios-plugins.org/download/nagios-plugins-2.2.1.tar.gz`